# Using LIKE and LIMIT in sqlite queries in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing a function for an Android app, that should get the first 8 entries (names of cities) of a database which are matching a string.

This is my query:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
                "SELECT " + CITIES_NAME +
                        " FROM " + TABLE_CITIES +
                        " WHERE " + CITIES_NAME +
                        " LIKE " + String.format("%s%%", nameLetters) +
                        " LIMIT " + 8
                        , null);
```

This is the resulting error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LIMIT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT city_name FROM CITIES WHERE city_name LIKE berl% LIMIT 8
```

I have already checked out other questions on the platform, but could not find any solution helping me out. The database is tested and created correctly and also the search entry is in the database.

Could anybody help?

Comment: Does it work without the `= ?` bit?

Comment: Thanks, I've removed it (see update above). But the problem is still present.

Comment: Think you need quotes around the like string eg LIKE 'berl%' LIMIT 8

Comment: Thanks, that helped regarding the resulting error. (But for some reason the query just does get any data.)

Comment: **WARNING:** You should NOT use string concatenation with the + operator to insert user input in a SQL query. This cannot be emphasized enough. See my answer for a better solution to avoid this security flaw.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually aware of that problem and changed the query a bit to post it here.

Comment: @Yonjuni Note that using `LIKE ?` eleminates the problem you are asking about, too, because it automagically quotes the input string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WARNING: You should NOT use string concatenation with the + operator to insert user input in a SQL query.This leaves your app open to a SQL injection attack. I cannot emphasize this enough. Mitigating this common security flaw should be a top priority for all database developers.

Instead, you should use the `?` place holder syntax:

```
String query = "SELECT " + CITIES_NAME +
                    " FROM " + TABLE_CITIES +
                    " WHERE " + CITIES_NAME +
                    " LIKE ?" +
                    " LIMIT 8";
String[] args = {nameLetters + "%%"};
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, args);
```

Even if the database is small and only used for your individual app, it is best to make this syntax a habit. Then when you work on larger, more critical databases, you won't have to worry about this issue as much.

This also has the advantage that it quotes the input for you. You completely avoid the error which you encountered that prompted the original question.

Comment: Shouldn't the ", null);" be removed?

Comment: @Yonjuni Yes, just noticed that. It is fixed now. (Your suggested edit should have been approved. I didn't see it soon enough to take action myself and other moderators rejected it.)

Comment: What about `ContentValues`?

Comment: @cricket_007 [`rawQuery()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) uses a `String[]` array to specify the query parameters. You are probably thinking of [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

Comment: Oh, right. Though, I try to use query instead of rawQuery too

Comment: @cricket_007 Of course, query() also uses a String[], not ContentValues.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness I'll turn my comment into an answer, to hopefully help anyone else who may have this issue.

> Think you need quotes around the like string eg 
>   `SELECT city_name FROM CITIES WHERE city_name LIKE 'berl%' LIMIT 8`