# Android Sqlite database not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am simply trying to create a quiz app for that I am storing the data in the database . The following code is not working, and the app crashes every time I feed the data

```
public class QuestionFeedMainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;
    EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question_feed_main_page);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitQF);
        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.q);
        e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.o1);
        e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.o2);
        e4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.o3);
        e5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.o4);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String q = e1.getText().toString();
                String o1 = e2.getText().toString();
                String o2 = e3.getText().toString();
                String o3 = e4.getText().toString();
                String o4 = e5.getText().toString();
                if(q.equals("") || o1.equals("") || o2.equals("") || o3.equals("") || o4.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(QuestionFeedMainPage.this, "Please fill all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    SQLiteDatabase sql = openOrCreateDatabase("multip",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                    sql.execSQL("create table if not exists questions (sno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,question varchar,optionone varchar,optiontwo varchar,optionthree varchar,optionfour varchar)");
                    String s4 = "select * from questions where question='"+q+"'";
                    Cursor cursor = sql.rawQuery(s4,null);
                    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionFeedMainPage.this, "This question already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    else{
                        sql.execSQL("insert into questions values ('"+q+"','"+o1+"','"+o2+"','"+o3+"','"+o4+"')");
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionFeedMainPage.this, "Question Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e1.setText("");
                        e2.setText("");
                        e3.setText("");
                        e4.setText("");
                        e5.setText("");

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x55596f0a20 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x55594260c0
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@352760c
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table questions has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.fridaygmail.saurabh.multip, PID: 25409
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table questions has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied (code 1): , while compiling: insert into questions values ('x','x','x','x','x')
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                      at com.fridaygmail.saurabh.multip.QuestionFeedMainPage$1.onClick(QuestionFeedMainPage.java:48)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25409 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Can you include the error logs? Pretty hard to debug without them

Comment: Probably wont solve your issue, but you should also have a look at this answer on preventing SQL injection http://stackoverflow.com/a/41496437/1543839

Comment: `insert into questions values (` VALUES **should** be preceded by the fields list.

Answer (score 2):

You want to fill 5 values into a table with 6 columns. You don't want to insert  the primary key sno.

Something like this should work:

```
sql.execSQL("insert into questions (question,optionone,optiontwo,optionthree,optionfour) values ('"+q+"','"+o1+"','"+o2+"','"+o3+"','"+o4+"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much explains what's going on:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table questions has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied (code 1): , while compiling: insert into questions values ('x','x','x','x','x')

Try something along these lines:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO questions (question, optionone, optiontwo, optionthree, optionfour) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);

String q = e1.getText().toString();
String q1 = e2.getText().toString();
String q2 = e3.getText().toString();
String q3 = e4.getText().toString();
String q4 = e5.getText().toString();

statement.bindString(1, q); // These match to the five question marks in the sql string
statement.bindString(2, q1); 
statement.bindString(3, q2); 
statement.bindString(4, q3); 
statement.bindString(5, q4); 

long rowId = statement.executeInsert();
```

Comment: But I need to it to auto increment, for that what is the need of giving?

Comment: Edited to make the answer less generic

Comment: No worries. If it solved your issue, please don't forget to accept the answer.